# How to build a GenericDao without repeating CRUD, with Spring JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, reflection, jpa-2.0, crud

I have the following situation.
[image: Component System with Package]
In layer Domain Model have the following packages named:

1. **net.myapp.persistence.spec:** containing the Interface Class for operations on the domain contained in the DTO Classes
2. **net.myapp.dto:** containing the Object of Domain

while in the layer of Persistence have the following packages named:

1. **net.myapp.persistence.dao.impl** containing the Class which implement the operation of upper layer
2. **net.myapp.persistence.jpa.entity**, Entity containing the tables that represent the db

Now, I want to implement the Interface of operation of Domain Modell inside the package with a DaoImpl GenericDao to avoid repetition of CRUD operations, but have no idea where to start, even if I read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html) but I still do not think of anything.

PS: I use Spring Framework for injection of EntityManager and Hibernate how provider of persistence.

Comment: Someone at some idea of how to do?

Comment: I've done it before following this exact article. The only thing I changed was still building concrete DAOs for my entities with the domain-specific find methods instead of defining finders. What exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: I can not editing the layer  Domain Modell (Spec and DTO), because it is used by another upper layer

Comment: Do these DTOs map to Hibernate fine? Do they have primary keys that are of Java classes or other classes defined in the same model? Then you should be able to write DAOs similar to the ones in the article. You can use Spring AOP features to inject transaction handling at the level of yournet.myapp.persistence.spec either via XML configuration or by adding annotations to the corresponding interfaces.

Comment: How do your DTO objects relate to the Entities? Is there a one-to-one correspondence?

Comment: @Olaf: In this project, I configured with the Entity annotation JPA and Hibernate as the provider, injecting the EntityManager with Spring. So I can use the Spring AOP module, my only requirement is that I can not change the layer of the domain model because it is used by a top layer that do not have access. Classes DTO layer of Domain-Modell does not correspond to the Entity Persistence layer, why should I do a kind of mapping

Comment: In that case you have to apply the article to your Entities rather than DTOs. You will have to provide some translation between Entities and DTOs in your service layer/domain model.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but will proceed without this add-on package, however, because I have to map each single class in the DTO and I would like the benefits

Comment: I am afraid I lost you on this. Your DAO classes are in the net.myapp.persistence.dao.impl, right? Your entities are in the net.myapp.jpa.entity, correct? You can apply the patterns from the article to your DAO classes. Do you have any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library if you didnt want to write the generic dao on your own.

http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/